# How to read AVI video file on colab with opencv?

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory, avi

I just want to read AVI video on colab. And I have read MPEG video succeed with opencv on colab. Why I can't read AVI video on colab with opencv? My code just like this:

```
import cv2
path = '/content/video.avi'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
flag, frame = cap.read()
```

I am sure the file exists. Is this problem maybe releated with ffmpeg?

Comment: Path format may be wrong. when you tried .mp4 or others it is succesfull?

Comment: This path just a example for decribe problem. My truth path is '/content/drive/Datasets/video.avi'. And I have read MPEG video succeed .